# How to define a search procedure in for CPLEX OPL?

Tags: cplex, opl

Is there an example somewhere(I tried looking, cannot find any) where a problem is modeled using OPL and the model specifies a search procedure? I am interested in understanding how exactly to specify a search procedure. I couldn't find an OPL example in the /examples dir that specifies one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In opl examples you should have a look at steelmill

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllanguser/topics/opl_languser_script_in_cp_searchwrite.html

Regards

Comment: Is a search phase the same as a search procedure?